# Convert String to JSON in bash

Tags: json, bash, sh, jq

I have a string which is formated as a long string (no newlines) like so:

```
<NAME1>ID1>CODE1a>CODE1b>><NAME2>ID2>CODE2a>CODE2b>><NAME3>ID3>CODE3a>CODE3b>>
```

The idea is convert this string to JSON:

```
{
  "ID1": [
    "NAME1",
    "CODE1a",
    "CODE1b"
  ],
  "ID2": [
    "NAME2",
    "CODE2a",
    "CODE2b"
  ],
  "ID3": [
    "NAME3",
    "CODE3a",
    "CODE3b"
  ]
}
```

The question is I need that in one comand (something like `cat testfile.txt | sed "..." | tr "..."`)

I've tried to use `sed`, `tr`, `jq`, but no success, and I'm completely stuck.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing can be done using just jq, e.g.:

```
jq -R '
  sub("^<";"")
  | split(">><")
  | map(split(">"))
  | map( { (.[1]) : (.[0:1] + (.[2:] | map(select(.!="")))) } )
  | add
'
```

Comment: It is getting error: https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwDIbve4qYyzrEYdvbnAVxO3hQwatOaN1AZcpk86Q@e81Wi7nkz/cREqPbs7XXB0x2EAYA7dMwPKY4Q4xofEPb1JeOoVLEANXh/uM33TDvMPozeAGL97yIIOnDNOEFjPskksKvVXV16lg8mtMRKviA29dlGYTWppvFOudqlXG13GY5164Z@qE3gowYkHBGeCPJyAFJZySZLw

Comment: Sorry - there was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Perfect! I'll accept this one as the answer, because it's only using jq, although the other one does the job also!
Just one question, how is used the split function and why did you have (wrongly) the two args?

Comment: `split(STRING)` splits the input string at STRING, producing an array. (See the manual regarding the difference between `split` and `splits`.)  As for the typo - the original version I developed had a call to `gsub(_;_)` and I incorrectly edited it.